# Fetching sent mail associated to a draft mail using gmail api

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

I am trying to fetch sent mail associated to a draft mail using gmail api.

I have a messageId of a draft email. I am fetching the draft Id from the browser address bar url (Eg: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=1570432re9b57469)

After sending the message the email gets moved from the drafts to the sent box. Also the messageId gets changed for the sent mail.

Tried to fetch the draft using gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts javascript gmail api. But got the error "Requested entity was not found".

The message is not sent using gapi. The message is sent using the normal gmail compose window.

Is there any way to get the sent mail id associated to the draft mail using the draft messageId or any other reference?

Comment: What is the `id` field in the response of the `drafts/send` method? Isn't this the message id? `https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send`

Comment: The message is not sent using gapi

Comment: The message is sent using the normal gmail compose window

Comment: Do you happen to know the value of the `Message-Id` header?

Comment: I know the messageId of the draft email (like 15709ad2dd121212121)

Comment: I am referring to the rfc822 `Message-Id` header.

Comment: No. Don't know the value of rfc822 Message-Id

Comment: How did you obtain the draft id of the draft message?

Comment: I am fetching the id using 2 methods: from the browser address bar or using https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/drafts

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's an idea. When you fetch the `id`s of the draft message(s), do an extra request (for each draft if there are many of them) using the [drafts/get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/get) method, with `format=metadata` parameter to obtain the `Message-Id` header, which should be persistent. Then, when the message is sent, search for it using the value of that header, by making a request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=1&q=rfc822msgid:THEACTUALRFC822MESSAGEID
```

Comment: Thank you :) Let me try this

Comment: I tried to access the draft https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/my_email/drafts/draftId?access_token={access_token} But I am getting the error "Requested entity was not found."

Comment: Also after sending the message, the message gets deleted from drafts. And so it won't give the draft message object on drafts/get request.

Comment: You mentioned above that you fetch the draft ids using https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/drafts. Right after you do that request, do the `drafts/get` request that I suggest above. It should find the draft.

Comment: In some case I am fetching Id from the browser address bar only. Let me check the method you suggested again.

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question. Can you please check that? Thank you :)

Comment: @ArunDNambissan If your `drafts/get ` request finds nothing while the draft still exists, then you don't really have the id of the draft. In that case I cannot help you, you don't have anything about the draft, how could we potentially try to find it in `sent`?

Comment: When I am listing all drafts using gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts.list(), There is a draft mail with the id which I have. (before sending the mail)

Comment: Well, now that weird, isn't it? How can the draft be included in the list but when you try to retrieve information about it is not there? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi. I got the Message-Id header for the draft, but unfortunately it is not persistent. It changes once the draft is sent, so there is no way to search for the recently sent message this way. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? Indeed the RFC id also changes, so I can't see how I can link draft to sent message.